# What is the best way to get amplitude and frequency of sound from microphone input?

Tags: ios

I need to analyze the sound from iPhone microphone and draw noise histogram. What frameworks I can use for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use AVFoundation framework. There is AVAudioRecorder class which has method "peakPowerForChannel". You can find example of usage here https://github.com/dydus0x14/isandbox/blob/master/iOS/PeakVoiceView/PeakVoiceViewDemo/ViewController.swift:
I hope it will help you.

Comment: I followed this solution and I had to remove a single line to make it working i.e. AVEncoderBitRateKey: 16, Just remove it if your record?.prepareRecorder() is returning false.